# Linux - Bash - Get $releasever and $basearch values?

Tags: linux, bash, yum

I'm writing a bash script to pull packages from remote repos, using reposync, so I can point my nodes to pull locally. As such I am trying to keep the local repo configs as similar as possible to the usptream repo configs, like this:

```
# upstream
baseurl=http://mirror.freedomvoice.com/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/

# local
baseurl=http://user:password@repo.example.com/centos/stable/$releasever/os/$basearch/
```

Within the bash script, is there a cleaner way to get $releasever and $basearch values? I was thinking of doing the following:

```
yum_metadata=$(yum version nogroups)
```

Which returns:

```
Loaded plugins: versionlock Installed: 6/x86_64 360:6167019baac7e76f94c26320424dc41a7f046a70 version
```

Then regexing for the 6/x86_64 values. Kind of messy, and looking for a more elegant approach.

Comment: What would be the values for `$basearch` and `$releasever` from the above example?

Comment: Installed: 6/x86_64, 6 is releasever and x86_64 is basearch.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most distro uses the distroverpkg version to get the releasever and basearch.

If you look at /etc/yum.conf, you will see that distrover is set to redhat-release (for RHEL), enterpriselinux-release (for OEL), and others.

To get the package name:

```
distro=$(sed -n 's/^distroverpkg=//p' /etc/yum.conf)
```

To get the releasever:

```
releasever=$(rpm -q --qf "%{version}" -f /etc/$distro)
```

To get the basearch:

```
basearch=$(rpm -q --qf "%{arch}" -f /etc/$distro)
```

The new code above will try to get the package associated with a file `/etc/$distro`. Some Linux adds `/etc/redhat-release` to their package release.

If you get `file not owned by any package` then use the `/etc/*-release` file that came with your distro. It is probably `/etc/centos-release`.

You can check the appropriate `/etc/*-release` appropriate for this code by checking which file is packaged with centos.

```
rpm -qf /etc/*-release
```

Then use this file instead of the first line above.

```
distro=/etc/centos-release
```

Here's an example from OEL where `/etc/redhat-release` is packaged as `enterprise-release`.

```
rpm -q --qf "%{name}" -f /etc/redhat-release
```

Output:

```
enterprise-release
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on centos 6.x. I keep getting `package redhat-release is not installed`

Comment: You can change the query as long as the file /etc/redhat-release is part of a package. Or if there is /etc/centos-release. I'll modify the code above shortly.

Comment: Sweet thanks... I'll kick around the new stuff in a few and get back at ya.

Comment: Your updates worked as described. Giving a +1, going to accept in a few days if nothing else turns up. Thanks again.

Comment: Accepting as I was able to implement your suggestion and worked fine.

Comment: FYI ineffective for Fedora 31; the `%{arch}` macro expands to `noarch` :(

Comment: @CraigRinger - This answer has been a while. `basearch=$(rpm —eval %{_arch})` should work even on fedora.

Comment: @alvits Confirmed. Thankyou. It's quite ridiculous that RH/Fedora don't offer a convenient, documented and stable interface for this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can print all conf using python.

Cf. post from [@Mark_McKinstry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3852/mark-mckinstry) :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/yum-how-can-i-view-variables-like-releasever-basearch-yum0

Comment: Except python is not universal.  You need to import "yum" on some systems and "dnf" on others and the output can be slow!