# yum_repository module fails properly insert *repo configuration file

Tags: ansible, yum, epel

there, I am having an issue if anybody had encountered and solved it, please share your knowledge.

---

Machine: 
**CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"**

epel.yml

```
 - name: Add repository
   yum_repository:
     name: epel
     description: epel-repo
     baseurl: https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch/
```

ansible-playbook epel.yml (I have removed not necessary part of the epel.yml)

Above, code when run successfully enters epel.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder. However, when I try to install any package it gives me en error referring "Failed to connect. Network is unreachable"

I have checked #cat /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

`baseurl=https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel///` 
I searched for where $releasever adn $basearch variables come from? Not very concrete answers around. 
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like yum couldn't determine $releasever and $basearch. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988371/linux-bash-get-releasever-and-basearch-values) for the possible reasons why this wasn't possible.

To workaround the problem, you could try using the yum module instead:

```
- name: install the latest version of epel
  yum:
    name: epel-release
    state: latest
```

Or install it directly from the rpm package:

```
- name: install from url
  yum:
    name: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
    state: present
```